# How can I default to the numeric keypad on focus of an EditText view?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an EditText field for the user to enter their weight in lbs. How can I override the traditional keyboard and display the numeric keypad instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This didn't work for me. However, I was able to accomplish the aforementioned by either of the following lines:

```
// TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: Class for numeric text. This displays the numbers/symbols keyboard.
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

// TYPE_CLASS_PHONE: Class for a phone number. This displays the phone number keypad.
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i pulled off of the google API

```
//Set the input style to numbers, rather than qwerty keyboard style.
txtView.setInputMethod(DigitsInputMethod.getInstance());
```