# Is there a way to show the numbers first on the soft keyboard for Android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I've tried every variation I can think of for input type and raw input type, but I can't get it so that the number keyboard shows first, but then allows you to toggle back to the text keyboard. Right now if you specify text|number, or number|text, the letters always show first, and then you have to toggle to the number keyboard. Is it possible to do the opposite?

Comment: Do you need just numbers or do you need the special characters as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show the number keyboard on an EditText in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119583/how-do-i-show-the-number-keyboard-on-an-edittext-in-android)

Comment: @George Cummins That does not appear to work in all devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my research and Bert B.'s comment, there is no way to do this cross-device compatible.

Comment: Dissapointing answer. It looks like it should be so easy. I have tried programatically clicking the keyboard, Dispatching keyevents tot no avail. It really seems impossible

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
android:inputType="number"
```

into your EditText field. This should automatically trigger the keyboard to show the number pad first.

Comment: I'm testing on the Galaxy Tab, and this does not work. The "ABC" in the bottom does not work. It won't toggle back.

Comment: Oh right, that would make that numbers only. Try this suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3034287/how-can-i-default-to-the-numeric-keypad-on-focus-of-an-edittext-view

Comment: All that does is programmatically change the keyboard. You still can't switch back to the other one.

Comment: You know, I don't think it's possible. Even this guy asked ~2 years ago and didn't see an answer http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/23ca35f83e1ca4b6?pli=1

Comment: I think you are correct because I came across that same message board and one other one, and nobody seems to have an answer. It appears if you specify that text and number are allowed, the text keyboard will always show first.

Comment: I believe that you are right in that conclusion. I find it weird that it's not possible to default to a numeric keyboard with the option of switching back. I guess it's time to file it as a bug! http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html