# How to switch to numeric with special characters keyboard of EditText in Android by default

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-inputtype

I want to show this keyboard by default on EditText focus:

[image]

These actions didn't help:

```
inputType=number
inputTYpe=phone
numeric=integer
setRawInputType(...)
```

How should I do it?

Comment: Discussed in some detail here: [How to show Android keyboard with symbols mode by default?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25219855/3264740).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That old problem still not solved. There's no way to show numeric keyboard with option of switching back.

This question discussed here [Is there a way to show the numbers first on the soft keyboard for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113157/is-there-a-way-to-show-the-numbers-first-on-the-soft-keyboard-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

try to use this in java:

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);              
editText.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: looks exactly like this and it is not what I needed: https://www.dropbox.com/s/71z16l0xexrc8ux/Screenshot%202015-10-13%2017.54.08.png?dl=0

Comment: well that depends on the device you are running on....i did spend a few minutes looking for it, thats what i found

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to achieve this. Even if your input method includes such a key panel, it's up to the keyboard "author". More importantly, the "even if" is even not guaranteed.